# Show that the same is not true in $ \mathbb{ R}^ n $, if $ n \geq 2 $.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

We know that any open $ (\mathbb{ R}, d) $ is the union of at most countable open balls disjunct two by two. Show that the same is not true in $ \mathbb{ R}^ n $, if $ n \geq 2 $.

I'm trying to show a counter example where I display an open set of R where A is not a joint of disjoint open balls.

Comment: The normal English for your *disjunct two by two* is *pairwise disjoint*.

Comment: You can use any open rectangle, together with the fact that the union of two or more pairwise disjoint open balls is not connected.

Comment: I thought to show that there are no open countable and disjunct balls in pairs whose union is the open square $(0,1)^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. I know it's because of the singing, but I don't know how to write it in mathematical terms.

Comment: Use the fact that the open unit square is connected, and prove that if $\mathscr{U}$ is a countable family of pairwise disjoint open balls, then $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ is not connected. (In fact its components are the members of $\mathscr{U}$.)